# How to change the "do" in ForEach loop command into self-defined text in algorithm2e?

Tags: algorithm2e

I am trying to write a pseudocode of a GPU-based parallel algorthm with algorithm2e.
Basically, I would like to write something like

> **foreach** GPU block **do in parallel**

How do I change the default "do" in the \ForEach command to "do in parallel"? Thanks!

Comment: Hello! In which way is this related to LaTeX?

Comment: @Roland Algorithm2e is a latex package.

Comment: I see. Providing a MWE would help you to draw attention to your question and getting an answer.

Comment: Chapter 11 of the manual (do `texdoc Algorithm2e`) describe how to define your own keywords, function names, etc etc (many pages). Based on the Italian keyword, it could be something like `\SetKwFor{ForBy}{for}{do in parallel}{end for}`. How to use it and in what context, I do not know. This is where example code helps greatly. Hopefully, a master of the package might see your question (and example code) and be able to respond.

Comment: @Cicada That's exactly what I need. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @edwardliang2019 If it works for you, you can self-answer and self-accept, so that others can see what worked for you. I don't know enough about `algorithm2e`.